# How to process Paypal Checkout to paypal app instead of web browser

Tags: php, paypal, checkout, payment-processing

Okay, so I have a unique issue with Paypal. I have a payment form that is working just fine. But I want something like, when people hit the payment button from their mobile it would take them straightly to their installed Paypal app to process the payment. For desktop, the browser is okay.

Can anybody help me anyhow with this? I don't even know if this is possible without SDK. I am using simple payment form

```
<?php
$paypalData = getPaypalData($userid);
$paypalurl = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
$paypalSandboxurl = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
?>
<form action="<?=$paypalurl;?>" method="post" target="_top">
<input type='hidden' name='business' value='<?=$paypalData['paypal_email'];?>'> 
<input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='Booking'> 
<input type='hidden' name='item_number' value='12345'> 
<input type='hidden' name='user_id' value='<?=$userid;?>'> 
<input type="hidden" name='amount' id="depositAmountform" value="">
<input type='hidden' name='no_shipping' value='1'>
<input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='USD'> 
<input type='hidden' name='notify_url' value='<?=$notifyURL;?>'>
<input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='<?=$cancelReturnURL;?>'>
<input type='hidden' name='return' value='<?=$successReturnURL;?>'>
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick"> 
<button type="submit" name=" " id="pay_now">PayPal</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What does PHP have to do with your question?

Comment: Switching to a current version of the PayPal Checkout https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/  is a much better use of your time than worrying about the PayPal mobile app (which for many mobile payers isn't likely to be installed anyway)

Comment: @M.Eriksson I have developed the project using PHP, that was the reason I added PHP as a tag ;)

Comment: @PrestonPHX I know, but the thing is, it's not about what I like. It's about what the client wants...

Comment: Sure, but you should only add tags that are relevant to your question/issue. you're asking about As far as I can tell, this has nothing to do with PHP. If I'm wrong, please edit your question to clarify where and how it comes into play.